# Is there another way to do serialization apart from implementing Serializable & Externalizable?

Tags: java, serialization

Is there any other mechanism to do serialization? one of interviewer asked me to tell about another way of serialization apart from implementing Serializable & Externalizable.

Comment: You could write your own implementation...

Comment: More ways than I can count. Serialization is merely the process of persisting state. You can do this in many, many ways.

Comment: You could serialize as JSON, use protobufs, avro, csv... serialization just means taking the information in an object and writing it somewhere, such that you can later read what you wrote and recreate a similar object. There are tons of ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way now is JSON